# afterSplitTable event in iText 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

In iText 5 we were able to do some logic (like repeating content) when a table was split over several pages
(see [iText: how to repeat table cell content on new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50971291/2413976))

I can not find the `Table.setTableEvent` method to activate the `afterSplitEvent` logic anymore. What is the iText 7 way to achieve my desired logic (repeat some cells with custom content)?

**Example**

- If the page breaks in the middle of 2012 (first column), I want to write "still 2012" in the first row on the new page. This was fairly easy with the `afterSplitTable` event in iText 5.

  [image: Example]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: H, did you check this -https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/splitting-tables

Comment: Hello, thank you for the link. Unfortunately, these examples only show how to split a table across two pages. What i need is some event/observer etc. to get the information that the table was split to a new page and then react to that event by doing my custom logic.